# OpenVINO 1D CNN model input tensor failed to set input blob with precision FP64 if CNNNetwork input blob precision is FP32

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, openvino

I try to inference my 1D CNN model with OpenVINO API 2.0.

My input is a CSV file with several signal records, so I use `model.reshape` to set a dynamic input size.

```
import openvino.runtime as ov
import numpy as np

core = ov.Core()
signal = np.genfromtxt('A4C_LV_V.csv')
model = core.read_model(model="saved_model.xml")
model.reshape([1, signal.size])
compiled_model = core.compile_model(model, "CPU")
infer_request = compiled_model.create_infer_request()
input_tensor = ov.Tensor(array=signal, shared_memory=True)
infer_request.set_input_tensor(input_tensor)
infer_request.start_async()
infer_request.wait()
output = infer_request.get_output_tensor()
output_buffer = output.data
```

But I encounter the error below.

```
RuntimeError: [ PARAMETER_MISMATCH ] Failed to set input blob with precision: FP64, if CNNNetwork input blob precision is: FP32
```

If I comment line 11: `infer_request.set_input_tensor(input_tensor)` .

The error will be solved and inference successfully.

I have no sense in deleting `set_input_tensor` still can work normally.

And here comes my inference [files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GPDRx7Ma4VanUgEp65EDKDZlKMRdsTLW/view?usp=sharing).

(The ZIP file contains 3 IR files and 1 input file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your model's precision is incorrect. Please ensure that your model had been properly converted into the right precision.

There are 3 common supported model precision for OpenVINO: FP32, FP16, and INT8

You may refer [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/should-i-choose-fp16-or-fp32-for-my-deep-learning-model.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF8ypHyiKrY) for further info.

If you would like to feed the model an input that has a different size than the model input shape, OpenVINO does provide capabilities to change the model input shape during the runtime. Use Reshape method to change the input shape of the model with a single input. Refer [here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_OV_UG_ShapeInference.html?sw_type=switcher-python) for further details.

There are models that support input shape changes before compilation. For this use case, [this](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/openvino_docs_OV_UG_DynamicShapes.html) is how you can configure the model.

Comment: I converted my model precision to FP16.

Comment: Your error indicates that your CNNNetwork input blob precision is: FP32. Try to change it to FP16 then and make sure to set the input blob with FP16 precision too.